# How to change the color palette of the Terminal in Gnome Builder?

Tags: appearance, gnome-builder

I'm getting started with this editor. I switched to `Appearance` and selected `Nord`, which is my favorite:

[image: selected nord]

But the appearance of the terminal didn't change:

[image: terminal appearance not changed]